# react addEventListener with redux, how to read updated props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a component react that have an event listener, my problem is that this.props have always the same value, and don't change same, that's not a problem if a have method direct without addEventListener

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('message', this.readMessage);
  }

  readMessage =  (event) => {
    console.log(this.props);
  };
```

I don't know how to update the values or read the new real value. this.props have always the same value and does not change. from readMessage() how i can read the new values, or retrieve it from redux?

Comment: A couple of questions. 1) Have you connected your component to your redux-store? 2) If you have, what is the prop you want to check?

Comment: I came across this same problem in my work lately. It was weird, in that if I used state to store the information, the event listener got the updated values, but if I had the information in _props_ then the event listener only ever had the *initial* values. My solution was so remove and re-add the event listener on `componentDidUpdate`, though if any can figure out a better way of doing it I'd I would love to hear.

Comment: 1) yes, always work when I use this.readMessage without addEventListener, 2) they are plenty of complex properties and states from a large app working

Comment: @Jayce444 please how reove and  re-add the event?

Comment: @Jayce444 my problem i'm in a popup windows, that calls this addEventListener, from there i can't remove and add; because a method laucnh this event...